# Linking display of hamburger icon with custom breakpoint

Tags: zurb-foundation

In my `foundation_and_overrides.scss`, I have changed the `topbar-breakpoint` to a particular `px` width. I'd like to display the hamburger icon when the width is less than the breakpoint.

Right now it removes the menu and leaves it blank until I hit `$small-range`. I'm not sure where to edit within the `foundation_and_overrides.scss` to display the hamburger icon/menu when it hits the new breakpoint.

SCSS

```
$topbar-breakpoint: 1225px; // Change to 9999px for always mobile layout
$topbar-media-query: "only screen and (min-width: #{$topbar-breakpoint})" !default;
```

HTML

```
<div class="fixed header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;">
  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="/"><img src="/assets/logo.png" alt="" id="logo-image"></a></h1>
      </li>

      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
     </ul>

<section class="top-bar-section">
  <ul class="left">
    <li><a href='/programs'>Programs</li>
    <li><a href='/projects'>Projects</li>
  </ul>
</section>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show us your html

Comment: Do you have the transition breakpoint styles uncommented in your settings file?